# Discussing real estate appreciation: Compound vs. simple interest?

Tags: real-estate, interest-rate, calculation, rate-of-return

When people say real estate has appreciated 8 % over the past 5 years, do they mean 8 % compounded annually? or simple interest annually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically related to real estate prices they mean simple interest.  For example assume in 2005 a property is worth $100,000.00.  In 2010 that property would be worth $108,000.00.

Answer (score 0):

They are talking about a beginning and ending point.  If you are trying to forecast appreciation for an investment over many years, use compound interest.